# Difference between grep and perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have a problem with what I think is a difference in grep's regex and perl's regex. Consider the following little test:

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
A line of text
SOME_RULE = $(BIN)
Another line of text

$ grep "SOME_RULE\s*=\s*\$(BIN)" testfile.txt 
SOME_RULE = $(BIN)

$ perl -p -e "s/SOME_RULE\s*=\s*\$(BIN)/Hello/g" testfile.txt
A line of text
SOME_RULE = $(BIN)
Another line of text
```

As you can see, using the regex "SOME_RULE\s*=\s*$(BIN)", grep could find the match, but  perl was unable to update the file using the same expression. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Is that gnu grep? And is that shell bash?

Comment: I'm sorry for failing to provide that information in my question. It was indeed bash and gnu grep. Thanks everyone who participated, I appreciate it!

Comment: As a side note, what the Perl code is trying to do here is a typical use case of [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl wants the '(' and ')' to be escaped.  Also, the shell eats the '\' on the '$', so you need:

```
$ perl -p -e "s/SOME_RULE\s*=\s*\\$\(BIN\)/Hello/g" testfile.txt
```

(or use single quotes--which is highly advisable in any case.)

Comment: In fact it would be better to escape the `$` too because when using double quotes, `$` marks the beginning of an environment variable name and is expanded (by shell) to its value. In this particular case, it doesn't make a difference because it is followed by a backslash which cannot be the name of an environment variable but if for example it were followed by a letter, it would have led to unexpected outcome. Therefore, I suggest using `"...\\\$\("...` (i.e. three backslashes, using the first one to escape the second backslash and the third one to escape the dollar sign).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `(` and `)`(Capturing group).

```
perl -p -e 's/SOME_RULE\s*=\s*\$\(BIN\)/Hello/g' testfile.txt
```

Actually you need it in Extended Regular Expression([**ERE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Perl-derived_regular_expressions)):

```
grep -E "SOME_RULE\s*=\s*\$\(BIN\)" testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '(/SOME_RULE\s*?=\s*?\$\(BIN\)/) && print' testfile.txt
```

If you want to modify use

```
perl -pe 's/SOME_RULE\s*?=\s*?\$\(BIN\)/Hello/' testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl's regex syntax is different to the POSIX regexes used by grep. In this case, you're falling foul of parentheses being metacharacters in Perl's regexes - they denote a capturing group.

You should have more success by altering the Perl regex:

```
s/SOME_RULE\s*=\s*\$\(BIN\)/Hello/g
```

which will then match the literal parentheses in the source text.