# In a shell script, using grep with a regex to find text in a file does not work

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file called `test.txt` with the following contents:

```
1 2 3
```

I have the following script that uses a regular expression to match at least one whitespace character between the numbers:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! grep -q -e "1[ \t]+2[ \t]+3" test.txt; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```

Executing the script prints out `not found`, but it should have print out `found`.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Per the grep man:

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
>   lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?,
>   \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

Try:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! grep -q -e "1[ \t]\+2[ \t]\+3" test.txt; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks.  An alternative would be to just change the `-e` to `-E`.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not quite working - the script prints out `not found` if I change the spaces in `test.txt` to tabs.

Comment: My man says `-P` is "highly experimental", so I'll change the ` \t` to `[:space:]` instead.  Thank you!

Comment: @pacoverflow Sorry, I should have caught that! `\t` won't work with `grep` because grep uses a POSIX regex definition (which doesn't define `\t` as a tab character). You easily work around this by just pasting a literal tab character into your pattern. 

Alternatively, depending on your environment, you can try using the `-P` flag to tell `grep` to use the PERL regex definition. I think there are other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to edit the other answer, which is incorrect as it currently stands.  But the edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16983247), so I'll have to post my own answer, given that comments are "[second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity [and] may get cleaned up at any time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)"

As mentioned in the other answer, the `-e` option only supports basic regular expressions (meaning that `+` does not have special meaning).  Therefore the `-E` option should be used for extended regular expressions, which support the `+` metacharacter.

In addition, grep only supports POSIX regular expressions, which do not recognize `\t` as a tab character.  The easiest way to fix this, while still maintaining readability and without using any experimental grep options (such as `-P`) is to replace `[ \t]` with `[[:space:]]`.

Therefore the fixed script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! grep -q -E "1[[:space:]]+2[[:space:]]+3" test.txt; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It has been unaccepted. BTW, I looked at the 2 questions you cited while closing the question as a duplicate, and I do not think they apply. The [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805676/difference-between-grep-and-perl-regex) is about perl regex, which I am not using. The [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233159/grep-regex-whitespace-behavior) is about `\s` which I am not using and the answer even mentions using `\t` which is incorrect for my situation.

Comment: Gotcha. I read `\t` as something taken from PCRE engines, but you make a strong enough case -- reopened.